# After moving out of the US, should I wait until I'm no longer a resident for tax purposes before investing in EU-domiciled accumulating ETFs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, international

I'm a EU citizen (and US non-citizen) who recently moved back to EU from the US. I liquidated my US investments and my plan is to invest in EU-domiciled accumulating index fund ETFs (such as [VUAA](https://americas.vanguard.com/institutional/mvc/detail/etf/overview?portId=9694&assetCode=EQUITY)).

I'm a US resident for tax purposes for this year.

Since non-US ETFs are classified as [PFICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_foreign_investment_company), I'm concerned that my tax situation would become complex  for this year. Many resources, such as [Bogleheads wiki](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Passive_foreign_investment_company#For_non-US_citizens_living_in_the_US), strongly recommend to avoid PFIC taxation which seems to be designed as punitive.

What should I keep in mind if I want to invest in such ETFs this year? Or should I just wait until the next year when I'm no longer filing US taxes as a resident?